# How to detect when user denies Google fit permission in expo

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-permissions, expo

In our app, we would like to know if user accepted or denied giving us access to google fit. Is it possible?

[The expo API](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/pedometer/) has a function `isAvailableAsync` that checks if the device has the right sensors. ([Android code behind](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-sensors/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/sensors/modules/PedometerModule.java#L67))

When it’s called in an android device, i get the google fit permission prompt. Is this expected behaviour?

How can i detect when user denies access to google fit?

Comment: I’m not sure if you can. It’s not currently listed as one of the permissions you can manually request. Though it is listed as on if the _dangerous_ permissions that Android makes you request permission from the user before accessing https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups

Comment: Thank you @Andrew that's what i thought as well.